# Sorting eventlog in powershell

Tags: powershell, command

I am using a command that will display the eventlog of a remote machine and filter it by the eventId. What I am trying to do is have it only show me the recent X events. Like 1, 5, 10, however many I specify. I says to use `-newest 5` , but when I try to get newest events after filtering them by eventId for example, it won't let me do it

```
Get-EventLog system -computername c78572 | select eventid,machinename,timewritten | where {$_.eventid -eq 6009} | ft -autosize
```

Basically I want to display a specific EventID of a remote system, and only show the most recent 5 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the InstanceId of the eventid then you can do:

```
Get-EventLog system -computername c78572 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 5
```

This is the long version:

```
Get-EventLog system -computername c78572  | 
where {$_.eventid -eq 6009} | 
select eventid,machinename,timewritten -First 5
```

Here's another way using the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet (the target should be vista and up iirc), which uses the eventid:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='system';Id=6009} -MaxEvents 5
```

Comment: Is the EventID 6009 have the same InstanceId every single time? How do you get that InstanceId then?

Comment: Pipe one 6009 event to fl and check its InstanceId property

Comment: I also think I'll stick to the Get-EvenLog because I need to get events of windows xp devices and higher.